# Jquery ui resizable height - default height:0px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: this picture is explain my problem]

my problem is basic.

I'm using jquery ui resizable,drag-drop and rotate, upload image resizable area for PHP...
It's all of work but, my problem uploaded picture width and height default automatically Zero - "0"

```
<img src="uploads/1378561827.jpg" id="elem-wrapper" class="ui-resizable" style="margin: 0px; resize: none; position: relative; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

I want, uploaded picture only width : 400px and height scale of width ...

Any solutions please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have set css `height: 0px; width: 0px;`

Try to change it to `width: 400px;`

Comment: I'am not set css...these css are add to jquery... I'am set to width: 400px; but height is "0px"...